# Selenium clicks on a wrong link (or does not click on a link at all) on certain machines

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver 2.5.0 (tried 2.13.0, it did not help).
I am trying to click on a link like this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("Customer - Creation").Click();
```

Before it worked, but I have tried to run the scripts after 3 weeks and
I observe 3 different behaviors on 3 machines:

1. Machine A: There is no click on the link at all, also there is no error.
2. Machine B: It clicks a different link! Sometimes one above, sometimes one below.
3. Machine C (Virtual): It works.

I have not fully tested this (spent half a day today), but did anyone stumble upon such a behaviour?

I have restarted my PC, re-added the Selenium libraries.
"SendKeys(Enter)" helps, but this issue happened not only to links, but to at least radio boxes as well, where "SendKeys(Enter)" does not work.

Please share your thoughts.

**Update**: Browsers are the same on at least 2 machines, Internet Explorer 8.0

Comment: Is this occurring with a specific browser driver, all browser drivers, the HTML driver? If a specific browser driver, are the browser versions in line across the 3 systems?

Comment: are they all the exact same browser? and which one?

Comment: Browsers are the same on at least 2 machines, Internet Explorer 8.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Answered by nebehr.g...@gmail.com at Selenium Issues:*

This issue keeps popping up from time to time and is usually returned with request for clarifications. The bottom line is, InternetExplorerDriver calculates coordinates of some objects incorrectly and clicks in the wrong place. One reason for this is zoom value other than 100%; however it is reproducible for some controls for 100% zoom as well.

I suppose it would be helpful if you could create a sample page to demonstrate this issue. In the meantime why don't you use Javascript click() method for offending controls?

*http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3052*

Comment: Is it possible that older versions of Firefox also have this problem?

Answer (score 4):

One other thing to check for is the screen resolution (not the desktop resolution but the system level size of text and icons). I have two laptops in my office that are you used for testing, one running Windows 7 and the other running Windows 10. On both, the screen resolution was greater than 100% and Selenium was having problems moving the mouse to the correct location for mouse events like click and hover. As soon as the screen resolution was set to 100%, all mouse actions worked correctly.

Windows 7: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/make-the-text-on-your-screen-larger-or-smaller?v=t

Windows 10: https://superuser.com/questions/951199/windows-10-system-font-size-change

Comment: This answer does help me. Thank you!

Comment: You saved my life! I was wasting a huge amount of time trying to figure out why my click didn't work properly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of useful info in Andrey's answer and in the Selenium issue he mentions at https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3052. Just to tie all those pieces of info together and offer a successful workaround...

I too am experiencing the issue of clicks occurring at the wrong screen coordinates -- four years after the OP first mentioned it! As others have said:

- The issue is related to InternetExplorerDriver. I have the problem
  when testing IE 9, but not Chrome, Firefox or even IE 8.
- As mentioned in the Selenium issue, the website I'm testing uses frames.

I tried several workarounds suggested in this post and elsewhere. All of the following did NOT help:

- Updating to the latest InternetExplorerDriver (version 2.47.0)
- Maximizing the browser window.
- Setting browser zoom to 100%.
- Using an action chain, with or without move_by_offset, instead of WebDriver's click() method.

As suggested by Andrey, what DID help is using JavaScript instead of WebDriver's click() method. Here's a line of Python code that does the trick:

```
driver.execute_script("jQuery('{}').click();".format(css_selector))
```

This assumes that "driver" is an instance of Selenium WebDriver, and "css_selector" is a string identifying the element you want to click, and that jQuery is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the element isn't present in the page's HTML, but is instead added dynamically once the page is loaded.  What happens depends on how fast the machine is and how unique the text is.  I'll bet that if you added a long sleep (*e.g.*, a minute) you'd get the same result on all 3 machines.  If so, that indicates the single most classic Selenium testing problem - trying to act on pages that aren't complete.  You need to find an element to wait on that will guarantee the presence of the link you'd like to click on.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue in FireFox. The zoom was at 100% and the selection was by xpath an certainly correct.  Turned out the problem disappeared when I maximized the browerwindow!

code :(python api)

```
   self.driver.maximize_window()
```